# Writing updated arrays to same worksheet, next to the original

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop

As I've tried to explain in the long title, I am writing an array to a worksheet. Then this array is used to update some coefficients that are to be used in calculating an updated version of that array (the P array). I would also like to write this array to the same worksheet, either in the row below, or transpose that array and write it in the column next to the first. This is to be done for all j's. Code to follow below

```
For j = 1 To Ntime    
    'Part A code    
    For i = 1 To n    
        'calculate an array P using the "Part A code"    
    Next i

    'Code below writes array P to cell D3 and below up to P(n_r). this P array is used to update the "Part A code" which updates the P array

    Set Destination_P = Range("D3")
    Set Destination_P = Destination_P.Resize(n_r, 1)
    Destination_P.Value = Application.Transpose(P)    
Next j
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Kind regards
Eirik

Comment: Make a for loop to run through your array. Then use Cells instead of range and increment either the row or column value for every run of the loop. So For k is 1 to ubound P Cells (3+k,3) = P(k) next k